# How to create chat room for question if SO didn't suggested the link

Tags: support

I have question with lot of comment exchange but SO didn't suggest to switch to chat:

[How to send response using jest function? It gives async callback error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636883/how-to-send-response-using-jest-function-it-gives-async-callback-error)

I've tried to create room:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/198414/how-to-send-response-using-jest-function-it-gives-async-callback-error

but it's seems it's public room like C++ and not this lightweight question chat.

So How can I create chat for a question if SO didn't provided the link?

Comment: What's wrong with a public room? Create it, and then post a link as a comment to your question

Comment: There is no difference between a "discussion" room for a question and a public room, except that the Feeds user created it and posts the link to the question as first message. And it doesn't have a room owner. And on the all rooms search page it shows up on a different place. It is ranked lower

Comment: Example: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/198411/discussion-between-gaurav-and-bill and https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/198403/discussion-on-question-by-m-millo-issue-with-an-addeventlistener